# How to fix my simple custom v-on directive that does not execute a method immediately?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am here to ask some help about why is my custom directive not working properly. I am trying to create my own v-on (named v-myOn) directive that would just change the background color of the text when it is clicked. The problem is that the method is executed instantly when vue js application is started (meaning the element background has the color style already) and not when a certain event happened which is when the element is clicked. Thanks in advance!

Update: Problem as what Phil stated is I execute the function directly in the template. But in this case I am trying to pass an argument to the method changeColor. So how could i prevent it from executing while being able to pass arguments?

Here is my code in App.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1 v-myOn:click="changeColor('blue')" :style="{background:  color}" ref="heading">Directives Exercise</h1>
                <!-- Exercise -->
                <!-- Build a Custom Directive which works like v-on (Listen for Events) -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return{
                color: ''
            }
        },


        directives: {

            myOn : {
                bind(el, binding, vnode) {
                    el.addEventListener(binding.arg, binding.value)
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeColor(color)
            {
                this.color = color;
            }
        }

    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: You are executing your `changeColor` function in your template

Comment: @Phil I see but may i know how can i pass a parameter into the function without executing it within the template?

Comment: Given how much of this directive depends on things outside the directive (input data, the event handling function, etc), what is the use-case? Is the above a real-world example or were you trying to simplify it for this question?

Comment: Wrap it in an arrow function: `v-myOn:click="() => changeColor('blue')"`

Comment: @Phil im just trying to create my own to test my concept regarding custom directives

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac it worked! Thank you! But I wonder why the arrow function fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap in an [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) otherwise it will get executed immediately as you have discovered and @Phil has pointed out.

```
<h1 v-myOn:click="() => changeColor('blue')" :style="{background:  color}" ref="heading">Directives Exercise</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate it! and thanks to @Phil for pointing out the problem as well.

Comment: Plus just wondering if you have any online reference that I can refer to on why the arrow function fixed it?

Comment: I'll get back to you in a few.